# git, rebase v interactive rebase, git directory strucuture

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-interactive-rebase

When I do `git rebase <base-commit>`, I see the directory `.git/rebase-apply` is created containing the files `onto`, `orig-head`, and `original-commit`, referencing `<base-commit>`, `head`,  and the current commit being applied respectively.

When I do `git rebase -i <base-commit>`, instead I see the directory `.git/rebase-merge` containing the files `onto`, `orig-head`, and `stopped-sha`, where `stopped-sha` seems equivilent to `original-commit`.

My question is why the discrepancy of file & dir naming between interactive and non-interactive rebase? And is my understanding of the files correct?

Comment: For people using git these are consequence-free implementation details. If you're curious anyway rebase is a script in libexec/git-core, if you want to try reimplementing it maybe that'll explain why it's done as it is.

Comment: @jthill: rebase *was* a script. Now it's mostly C code. The C code mostly does what the script used to do, but that's a lot of "mostly"... (In this particular case, the difference between `git-rebase--am` and `git-rebase--interactive` is preserved, but the scripts are starting to lose some of their relevance.)

Comment: @jthill: these details r actually important to me, because i rely on these files for my own script (to print a log of commits between `base` and `head` and highlight the `current-commit`. 

Can i assume these file structures will most likely stay stable?

Answer (score 2):

You have come across the difference between a `git format-patch | git am` style rebase and a `git cherry-pick` style rebase.  As [jthill noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52857890/git-rebase-v-interactive-rebase-git-directory-strucuture#comment92632014_52857890), these are not intended to be different in most cases for most users.  They were originally separated into two different back ends, spelled `git-rebase--am` and `git-rebase--interactive`.  (They still are, but the distinction is being weakened.)

There is one important difference between the two, having to do with file-rename detection.  Since the cherry-pick rebase literally uses the `git cherry-pick` machinery, which uses the underlying *merge* machinery, this enables rename detection.  Since the format-patch rebase does not, it does not.  Rename detection is slow, so if there are no renames, sometimes the format-patch variety goes faster.

You can force `git rebase` to use the cherry-pick mode without going to interactive rebase by adding `-m` or `-s <strategy>` or `-X <extended-strategy-option>` arguments to any rebase.